# ereader : how to implement bookmark by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks, epub

I am implementing an epubReader's app, which sets pagination by css3-multi columns.

My question is how to implement bookmarks by using Javascript? Does anyone have similar experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer by myself.
Each column is between a previous paragraph and a next paragraph.
Each column and each paragraph has a percent number.
In accordance with this method, we can compute an approximate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the FAQ at epubread.com](http://www.epubread.com/en/faq.php).

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your statement, can you explain clearly?^^"

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to remember the current file and your current scrollLeft in your scrolling container (but if you allow font size changes this is probably not very good.

I think the fullproof way to implement it would be to inject your own invisible anchor tag with a bookmark ID in the current visible location in the document and then just navigate to that when loading the file. SO to store a bookmark you would need the current XHTML file loaded and the bookmark ID to navigate to when this file is loaded.

Comment: 1. Yes. I allow the user to change font size or the reader is rotated.
2. How to inject a bookmark tag? I do not know where is the cross-page point, even the paragraph is very long and across many pages.